# Rotate UIImageView around its center

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, uiimageview, uibezierpath

I am trying to rotate two UIImage its centre and I am having an issue (you can check on the gif image below), the rotation is fine, but the images are bobbing up and down, would anyone know what it can be?

[Loader Animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiqEk.gif)

[Loader Animation with background color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmbqR.gif)

Here is the code that I am using to rotate the images

```
extension UIView {

private static let kRotationAnimationKey = "rotationAnimationKey"

func rotate(_ reversed: Bool = false, _ duration: Double = 1) {
    if layer.animation(forKey: UIView.kRotationAnimationKey) == nil {
        let rotationAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
        rotationAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
        rotationAnimation.toValue = reversed ? -(Float.pi * 2.0) : Float.pi * 2.0
        rotationAnimation.duration = duration
        rotationAnimation.repeatCount = Float.infinity
        layer.add(rotationAnimation, forKey: UIView.kRotationAnimationKey)
    }
}

func stopRotating() {
    if layer.animation(forKey: UIView.kRotationAnimationKey) != nil {
        layer.removeAnimation(forKey: UIView.kRotationAnimationKey)
    }
}
```

Thank you all!

Comment: It looks like your image asset isn’t centred properly. Set the background colour of your image view so you can tell. The image view is probably rotating about its center, but the image content itself is probably off center.

Comment: @PeterParker I believe so, I updated the post and added the image gif with the background. 

Do you know how to center the image content?

Comment: You’ll have to do it in photoshop.

Comment: Basically your image of the rings does not have the rings smack in the middle. So you need to put that image into photoshop and export a new one such that the rings are smack in the middle.

Comment: @PeterParker Thank you

Comment: cant you create two circle yourself ?

Comment: hello sir ... have you seen the solution provided by me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer below:

> It looks like your image asset isn’t centred properly. Set the background colour of your image view so you can tell. The image view is probably rotating about its center, but the image content itself is probably off center. - [Peter Parker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5606659/peter-parker)
>
> Basically your image of the rings does not have the rings smack in the middle. So you need to put that image into photoshop and export a new one such that the rings are smack in the middle.
> [Peter Parker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5606659/peter-parker)

Thanks [Peter Parker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5606659/peter-parker)

Answer (score 1):

Created a circular view for this animation Using ShapeLayer and UIBezierPath you can use this class

```
public class CirclesView: UIView {

    //MARK:- properties
    private var numberOfCircles: Int = 2
    private var lineWidth: CGFloat = 8.0
    private var space = 20
    private var color : UIColor = .white
    private static let kRotationAnimationKey = "rotationanimationkey"

    private lazy var circularLayer: CAShapeLayer = {
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = color.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineCap = .round
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = self.lineWidth

        return shapeLayer
    }()

    //MARK:- inializer

    public init(_ circles: Int, circleWidth: CGFloat) {
        self.numberOfCircles = circles
        self.lineWidth = circleWidth
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        addSubLayer()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {

        super.init(frame: frame)
        addSubLayer()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {

        super.init(coder: coder)
        addSubLayer()
    }

    override public func layoutSubviews() {

        super.layoutSubviews()
        addCircles()

    }


}
private extension CirclesView {

    func addCircles() {
        circularLayer.bounds = self.bounds
        let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()

        let center = CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX / 2, y: bounds.maxY / 2)
        let maximumRadius =  min(bounds.maxX,bounds.maxY)/2 - (lineWidth / 2.0)
        var startAngle = CGFloat(60)
        var endAngle = CGFloat(130)


        for i in 1...numberOfCircles {

            let radius = maximumRadius - CGFloat(i * space)
            let  startX = center.x  + (radius) * CGFloat(cos(startAngle.deg2rad()))
            let  startY = center.y  + (radius) * CGFloat(sin(startAngle.deg2rad()))

            bezierPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: startX,y: startY))
            bezierPath.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: startAngle.deg2rad(), endAngle: endAngle.deg2rad(), clockwise: false)

            startAngle = startAngle - 10
            endAngle = endAngle + 50

        }

        circularLayer.path = bezierPath.cgPath
    }

    func addSubLayer() {
        self.backgroundColor = .clear
        layer.addSublayer(circularLayer)

    }


}

 //MARK:- Public Functions
public extension CirclesView {

    func startAnimation(_ reversed: Bool = false, _ duration: Double = 1) {

        let rotateAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
        rotateAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
        rotateAnimation.toValue = reversed ? -(Float.pi * 2.0) : Float.pi * 2.0
        rotateAnimation.duration = duration
        rotateAnimation.repeatCount = Float.infinity
        self.circularLayer.add(rotateAnimation, forKey: Self.kRotationAnimationKey)
    }

    func stopAnimation() {
        if let _ = circularLayer.animation(forKey: Self.kRotationAnimationKey)  {

            let rotateAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
            rotateAnimation.fromValue = circularLayer.presentation()?.value(forKeyPath: "transform.rotation")
            rotateAnimation.toValue = 0
            rotateAnimation.duration = 0.5
            rotateAnimation.repeatCount = 0
            rotateAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = true
            self.circularLayer.removeAnimation(forKey: Self.kRotationAnimationKey)
            self.circularLayer.add(rotateAnimation, forKey: Self.kRotationAnimationKey)
        }
    }

    func pauseLayer(){
        let pausedTime : CFTimeInterval = layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil)
        circularLayer.speed = 0.0
        circularLayer.timeOffset = pausedTime
    }
}


 extension CGFloat {
    func deg2rad() -> CGFloat {
        return self * .pi / 180
    }
}
```

[Github Project Link](https://github.com/jwd-ali/CircularAnimation)

[image]

Comment: Thanks @jawadAli I'll try first with images because my client may change a few things, but I already downloaded your project if I need it in the future